# Create React App + Webpack only show blank page

Tags: webpack, create-react-app

I've been trying to get my head around this for way too long now. My goal is to create a single bundle from my Create React App app. I'm following the much acclaimed steps here:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3365#issuecomment-376546407

- I use create react app 3.3.0 to create a React app.
- I add a console.log right after the import statements of the generated src/index.js
- I run yarn build and then webpack --config webpack.config.js (installed version: 4.41.2). No errors.
- I include the generated bundle from dist/build/bundle.min.js in html and load the page. The file contents are loaded correctly according to the network tab.
- **But no console.log! And the site just stays blank.**

Any ideas? I'm attaching the bundle.min.js fyi.

Thank you

```
!function(e){var t={};function n(r){if(t[r])return t[r].exports;var o=t[r]={i:r,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[r].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,n),o.l=!0,o.exports}n.m=e,n.c=t,n.d=function(e,t,r){n.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},n.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},n.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=n(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(n.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var o in e)n.d(r,o,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,o));return r},n.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return n.d(t,"a",t),t},n.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},n.p="",n(n.s=0)}([function(e,t,n){n(1),e.exports=n(5)},function(e,t,n){var r=n(2);"string"==typeof r&&(r=[[e.i,r,""]]);n(4)(r,{insert:"head",singleton:!1}),r.locals&&(e.exports=r.locals)},function(e,t,n){(e.exports=n(3)(!1)).push([e.i,"body{margin:0;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,Fira Sans,Droid Sans,Helvetica Neue,sans-serif;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing:grayscale}code{font-family:source-code-pro,Menlo,Monaco,Consolas,Courier New,monospace}.App{text-align:center}.App-logo{height:40vmin;pointer-events:none}@media (prefers-reduced-motion:no-preference){.App-logo{-webkit-animation:App-logo-spin 20s linear infinite;animation:App-logo-spin 20s linear infinite}}.App-header{background-color:#282c34;min-height:100vh;display:flex;flex-direction:column;align-items:center;justify-content:center;font-size:calc(10px + 2vmin);color:#fff}.App-link{color:#61dafb}@-webkit-keyframes App-logo-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(1turn);transform:rotate(1turn)}}@keyframes App-logo-spin{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);transform:rotate(0deg)}to{-webkit-transform:rotate(1turn);transform:rotate(1turn)}}",""])},function(e,t,n){"use strict";e.exports=function(e){var t=[];return t.toString=function(){return this.map((function(t){var n=function(e,t){var n=e[1]||"",r=e[3];if(!r)return n;if(t&&"function"==typeof btoa){var o=function(e){var t=btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(e)))),n="sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,".concat(t);return"/*# ".concat(n," */")}(r),a=r.sources.map((function(e){return"/*# sourceURL=".concat(r.sourceRoot).concat(e," */")}));return[n].concat(a).concat([o]).join("\n")}return[n].join("\n")}(t,e);return t[2]?"@media ".concat(t[2],"{").concat(n,"}"):n})).join("")},t.i=function(e,n){"string"==typeof e&&(e=[[null,e,""]]);for(var r={},o=0;o<this.length;o++){var a=this[o][0];null!=a&&(r[a]=!0)}for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){var s=e[i];null!=s[0]&&r[s[0]]||(n&&!s[2]?s[2]=n:n&&(s[2]="(".concat(s[2],") and (").concat(n,")")),t.push(s))}},t}},function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r,o,a={},i=(o={},function(e){if(void 0===o[e]){var t=document.querySelector(e);if(window.HTMLIFrameElement&&t instanceof window.HTMLIFrameElement)try{t=t.contentDocument.head}catch(e){t=null}o[e]=t}return o[e]});function s(e,t){for(var n=[],r={},o=0;o<e.length;o++){var a=e[o],i=t.base?a[0]+t.base:a[0],s={css:a[1],media:a[2],sourceMap:a[3]};r[i]?r[i].parts.push(s):n.push(r[i]={id:i,parts:[s]})}return n}function c(e,t){for(var n=0;n<e.length;n++){var r=e[n],o=a[r.id],i=0;if(o){for(o.refs++;i<o.parts.length;i++)o.parts[i](r.parts[i]);for(;i<r.parts.length;i++)o.parts.push(h(r.parts[i],t))}else{for(var s=[];i<r.parts.length;i++)s.push(h(r.parts[i],t));a[r.id]={id:r.id,refs:1,parts:s}}}}function l(e){var t=document.createElement("style");if(void 0===e.attributes.nonce){var r=n.nc;r&&(e.attributes.nonce=r)}if(Object.keys(e.attributes).forEach((function(n){t.setAttribute(n,e.attributes[n])})),"function"==typeof e.insert)e.insert(t);else{var o=i(e.insert||"head");if(!o)throw new Error("Couldn't find a style target. This probably means that the value for the 'insert' parameter is invalid.");o.appendChild(t)}return t}var u,f=(u=[],function(e,t){return u[e]=t,u.filter(Boolean).join("\n")});function p(e,t,n,r){var o=n?"":r.css;if(e.styleSheet)e.styleSheet.cssText=f(t,o);else{var a=document.createTextNode(o),i=e.childNodes;i[t]&&e.removeChild(i[t]),i.length?e.insertBefore(a,i[t]):e.appendChild(a)}}var d=null,m=0;function h(e,t){var n,r,o;if(t.singleton){var a=m++;n=d=d||l(t),r=p.bind(null,n,a,!1),o=p.bind(null,n,a,!0)}else n=l(t),r=function(e,t,n){var r=n.css,o=n.media,a=n.sourceMap;if(o&&e.setAttribute("media",o),a&&btoa&&(r+="\n/*# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,".concat(btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(a))))," */")),e.styleSheet)e.styleSheet.cssText=r;else{for(;e.firstChild;)e.removeChild(e.firstChild);e.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r))}}.bind(null,n,t),o=function(){var e;null!==(e=n).parentNode&&e.parentNode.removeChild(e)};return r(e),function(t){if(t){if(t.css===e.css&&t.media===e.media&&t.sourceMap===e.sourceMap)return;r(e=t)}else o()}}e.exports=function(e,t){(t=t||{}).attributes="object"==typeof t.attributes?t.attributes:{},t.singleton||"boolean"==typeof t.singleton||(t.singleton=(void 0===r&&(r=Boolean(window&&document&&document.all&&!window.atob)),r));var n=s(e,t);return c(n,t),function(e){for(var r=[],o=0;o<n.length;o++){var i=n[o],l=a[i.id];l&&(l.refs--,r.push(l))}e&&c(s(e,t),t);for(var u=0;u<r.length;u++){var f=r[u];if(0===f.refs){for(var p=0;p<f.parts.length;p++)f.parts[p]();delete a[f.id]}}}}},function(e,t){(this.webpackJsonptest=this.webpackJsonptest||[]).push([[0],[,,,function(e,t,n){e.exports=n.p+"static/media/logo.5d5d9eef.svg"},function(e,t,n){e.exports=n(11)},,,,,function(e,t,n){},function(e,t,n){},function(e,t,n){"use strict";n.r(t);var r=n(0),o=n.n(r),a=n(2),i=n.n(a),s=(n(9),n(3)),c=n.n(s);n(10),console.error("Hello"),console.log("hello from here"),i.a.render(o.a.createElement((function(){return o.a.createElement("div",{className:"App"},o.a.createElement("header",{className:"App-header"},o.a.createElement("img",{src:c.a,className:"App-logo",alt:"logo"}),o.a.createElement("p",null,"Edit ",o.a.createElement("code",null,"src/App.js")," and save to reload."),o.a.createElement("a",{className:"App-link",href:"https://reactjs.org",target:"_blank",rel:"noopener noreferrer"},"Learn React")))}),null),document.getElementById("root"))}],[[4,1,2]]])}]);
```

Comment: There's a comment 5 posts further down that thread with a tweak to include additional files. My suspicion is that you're missing something in your bundle.

Comment: I think so too! I tried the comment further down (making the glob broader), but to no avail.

I noticed that CRA adds an inline script to the built index.html and when I don't add this script during injection the chunked bundle scripts don't do anything either. But in the Github issue nobody talks about this inline script.

Answer (score 1):

Try using react-scripts 3.1.1. Something changed some time after this version that made the steps you linked to stop working for me as well.

Comment: Thank you! I've been fighting the whole morning with this issue, using the same approach as before, but could not make it work.  
Downgrade to 3.1.1 worked perfectly:  
`yarn add react-scripts@3.1.1`